# Powershell - Cat out string in different colors

Tags: powershell, batch-file, base64

Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.
I am writing a simple base64 encoder for windows so I can encode strings faster when required.

The encoding happens in CMD and then the script opens a PowerShell in order to cat out the encoded string in the terminal.

For easier reading I am trying to change the color of the string that is retrieved with cat but am having a hard time achieving this. Here is a snippet of the code that is problematic:

```
certutil -encode data.txt tmp.b64 && findstr /v /c:- tmp.b64 > secret.b64
powershell.exe -Command "Write-Host Your secret is: -ForegroundColor Green";cat secret.b64
PAUSE
```

When the information is retrieved; "Your secret is: " is green as intended in the code but I cannot seem to find a way to color the "cat secret.b64" command.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? If you're using Windows 10, you can do this in pure batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it entirely in PowerShell; PS can call any console executables that CMD can. To take the stdout of a console executable and use it as string input to a PS cmdlet or function, either enclose the entire console executable's command in parens (e.g., `$foocontent = (cat.exe foo)`), or pipe it to a parameter of the PS cmdlet/function that accepts pipeline input (e.g., `cat foo | Format-Table`)

(Note that in PowerShell under Windows, `cat` is generally aliased to the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-Content`.)

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I was actually worried that the answer would be to do everything in PS. So there is no way to just change the color of the retrieved information from cat?

Comment: Not if you're working in CMD. What you're doing is loading PS as a subprocess of CMD, and CMD doesn't - to the best of my recollection - have controls for colorizing output. PS does, but when it's "in the hole" from CMD, it can't reach out.

Comment: Windows 10 has access to VT100 escape sequences, so you can `echo ESC[32m` to make the text green

Answer (score 2):

As far as the original request goes, I suppose you wanted something like:

```
powershell -command "$i = cat secret.b64; Write-Host Your secret is: $i -ForegroundColor Green"
```

You can however skip `powershell` and do `batch-file` only.

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "cl=%%a"
(certutil -encode data.txt tmp.b64 && findstr /v /c:- tmp.b64)>secret.b64
set /p secr=<secret.b64
echo Your secret is: %cl%[92m%secr%%cl%[0m
pause
```